# Does ScyllaDB Support Centos Stream 8-9?

Tags: linux, nosql, centos, centos7, scylla

I'm looking at the [list of supported OS](https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/os-support/) and I only see version 7 and 8 of `Centos/RHEL` are supported.

However, I plan on installing `ScyllaDB` on Ryzen 9 CPU [which does not support Centos 7 / 8](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=78604#p330281).

Does ScyllaDB support `Centos Stream 8 & 9`?

In general, is there one OS recommended over any other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with an answer to your 2nd question. ScyllaDB Image (for AWS EC2, GCP) is based on Ubuntu 20.04 since OSS release 4.3 and Enterprise release 2021.1 (as of [May 2021](https://www.scylladb.com/product/release-notes/scylla-enterprise-release-2021-1-0/)).
So that's the OS that gets the most QA coverage and the one that we recommend using.

I highly recommend you use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: OK, so Ubuntu is recommended over other OS but is Centos Stream 8 & 9 also supported? I don't see any mention about Centos Stream in the official documentation and Centos 7 & 8 are no longer being supported by the community. Thanks!